# Trouble with call function

Tags: python

I wrote the parser log_file.  But i can`t understand why I can not call a function in this block. 
Help me please.

[image]
[image]

Comment: please post your (or example) code here and provide full traceback if the issue you are facing

Comment: indent the code that's supposed to run in the `while` loop.

Comment: https://hello-site.ru/share/olHqaXcnTn8CaLM/  open this URL with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is dependant on indentation.  In order for the program to work you need to add the correct indentation to your code.  That involves 4 spaces for each loop or flow control.

Here are a few that do:

```
def 
if
while 
for
```

Your problem is that Python does not know where to end the while loop without indentation.

Here is an example:

```
for in range(5):
print('Working')
if i == 4: 
print('yes')
else: 
print('no')
```

There are two ways to indent this.

How does Python know whether the `if` statement should be in the for loop or not?  Both the following are valid with very different results:

```
for in range(5):
    print('Working')
if i == 4: 
    print('yes')
else: 
    print('no')
```

OR

```
for in range(5):
    print('Working')
    if i == 4: 
        print('yes')
    else: 
        print('no')
```

In the first the `while` prints out the message 5 times and then the `if` statement starts.

In the second the `if` is part of the while loop so it runs 5 times as well as printing the message.

Comment: Could u please help me debug my code?

Comment: @EverythingWillBeFine  Yes but that is the problem.  You have not set the indentation.  Everything you want to be run in the while loop takes an indent.  Once you want to quit the loop just no longer indent the code,  You are getting an error to say that Python does not know where to start running your while loop and where to quit it

Comment: As you have done with the `for` loop indent your while loop also

Comment: could u help me if i send to u my code in skype? Please